# Using probability instead on combinations in selection.

Tags: probability

Three letters have to chosen randomly from the word 'SCHOOL'. What is the probability that the selection contains no O's?

I thought that this would go :(4/6) x (3/5)x (2/4) since all 3 events must occur ( first pick not O. Second pick not O. third pick not O.)

My teacher used combinations and got a larger probability.

His reasoning ( the important bit) :
Combinations with no O's = 4C3

Combinations with 1 O= 4C2

Combinations with 2 O's =4C1.

Total combinations = 14

Prob ( no Os) = 4C3 / 14 = 2/7

Why do our answers not match?

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: "*Why do our answers not match*"  What answer did your teacher get?  Your answer appears correct to me.  You have the option of approaching different ways and the resulting expressions may vary slightly but will remain equal so long as no mistakes were made.  E.g. $\dfrac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{6}{3}}=\dfrac{4\times 3\times 2}{6\times 5\times 4}=\dfrac{4}{6}\times\dfrac{3}{5}\times\dfrac{2}{4}$

Comment: Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JMoravitz gave the answer in a comment, here is some more background.  You're using the correct intuition, the probabilities of each selection can just be multiplied (as they're independent) to yield the answer.  As the problem becomes more complex, you'll likely find solving such problems using combinations to be more useful.

Let's look at the teacher's assertion that there are $14$ possible combinations.  There are $6$ objects (letters) and we're selecting $3$, so there are ${6 \choose 3}=20$ combinations, not $14$.  The teacher is adding a subset of the possible outcomes by choosing $3$ letters, $2$ letters, and $1$ letter from a subset of $4$ letters.

Your teacher correctly asserts that there are ${4 \choose 3}=4$ unique ways to arrange $4$ letters (the non-O's) into groups of $3$.  These $4$ ways over $20$ possible ways yields the answer: ${4 \over 20}=0.2$ which is equivalent to your answer: ${4 \over 6} \times {3 \over 5} \times {2 \over 4}=0.2$.

Be kind to your teacher, but if he doesn't believe the math here, he can review the entire possibility space:

$SCH, SCO_1, SCO_2, SCL, SHO_1, SHO_2, SHL, SO_1O_2, SO_1L, SO_2L, CHO_1, CHO_2, CHL, CO_1O_2, CO_1L, CO_2L, HO_1O_2, HO_1L, HO_2L, O_1O_2L$

Comment: The  teacher counted the number of combos with $1$ O incorrectly since there are $2$ choices for the O along with the $4C2$ = $6$ choices for the other letters, for a total of $6*2 =12$ such combos. Thus $4+12+4=20$ combinations altogether.

Comment: That all makes sense finally.